# Google domain cookies are setting only after page reload

Tags: javascript, cookies, httpcookie, one-trust

I have a client's website where there are multiple cookies coming as seen in the 1st screenshot. However when I enter the website URL and only few of the cookies are setting which is not shown in the screenshot, and only after I reload the page, the cookies shown in the 1st screenshot are setting. These cookies are coming from google domain, I am trying to set these cookies as soon as user enters the url and hit enter rather than reloading the page. The website is also using one trust cookie banner, not sure if that is affecting. Please help

[image]

[image]